# How do i get current active view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having this issue (error is reported by Flurry analytics from some users, but I cannot reproduce it neither on my device nor simulator):

`NSInvalidArgumentException: Application tried to present modally an active controller <CityViewController: 0x361b20>.`

Do you know anything about this error? Has it happened to you?

Application has three hierachically sorted views: master view controller with list of locations and detail view (the CityViewController mentioned in error message) is automatically presented when user is at one of known locations. Whenever location significantly changes, detail view is dismissed first before opening new location to prevent this. However, it apparently doesn't help.

CityViewController can also open SMS composer as its child.

Comment: try with persendModelView without set Animation...i mean animation:NO

Comment: You can check whether a controller's view is on screen by looking at self.view.window -- that will be nil if the view is not currently in the window's hierarchy.

Answer (score 16):

To get the currently visible view you can use:

```
[self.navigationController visibleViewController];
```

Comment: Wouldn't  you need to cast it to the type of view controller you are using?

Comment: What will be happen if the app is not using the navigation controller?

Answer (score 2):

So the reply to original question: How do i get current active view controller?

The answer lies in `[self.navigationController presentedViewController]` instead of topViewController or anything else.

Comment: What is "self" in your answer? And how to get it from any part of the application?

Comment: The self refers to current class, the UIVewController subclass that is the first pushed into window.rootViewController = navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching the modal view when some event is fired, seems probable that you are trying to show that view again while it is already active...

Comment: Yes, that's why I was about to inspect whether it is already visible using some introspection instead of tracking using a state machine, that might take too much effort to keep it thread-safe.